# How do I calculate the invertibility of a linear transformation defined by a matrix?

Tags: functions, linear-transformations, matrix-calculus

In particular this:

[How would I go about calculating to see if f was invertible?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dLSs.png)

Comment: Check the determinant

Comment: Follow this example https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Det%5B%7B%7B1,+2,+3%7D,+%7B4,+5,+6%7D,+%7B7,+8,+2%7D%7D%5D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A linear map $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is invertible iff the corresponding matrix $A$ is such that $\det(A) \neq 0$.

Comment: I was going to say "use Google", but I couldn't find this question and answer here in 2 minutes, which I find surprising!